# use recursive cte with parameters in join

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables Product and Category
Every product has a CategoryId field. Categories are organized in a tree using the adjacency list pattern (every category holds the parent id and the roots parent is null).

I need to retrieve a list of products and add the product the category it points to and all of its parent categories.

I wrote this cte to get the upwards tree. In my tests it gave the expected results.

```
WITH RECURSIVE getCategories as (
    select id, name, ParentCategoryId as parent_id, updatedAt
    from Category
    where id = :leaf_id
    union
    select category.id, category.name, category.ParentCategoryId as parent_id, parentCategory.updatedAt
    from Category category
             join getCategories parentCategory on category.id = parentCategory.parent_id
)
```

I tried to use this cte directly inside the table join in a query of the following form

```
select p.*, C.*
from Product p
         cross join (
    WITH RECURSIVE getCategories as (
        select id, name, ParentCategoryId as parent_id, updatedAt
        from Category
        where id = p.CategoryId
        union
        select category.id, category.name, category.ParentCategoryId as parent_id, parentCategory.updatedAt
        from Category category
                 join getCategories parentCategory on category.id = parentCategory.parent_id
    )
    select *
    from getCategories
) C
```

I get the following error
`Unknown column 'p.CategoryId' in 'where clause'`.
I suppose it is not possible to use this field in an inner query.

I also tried creating a variable holding the current product id. This variable takes an unknown value since I get the tree

```
select p.*, C.*, @CategoryId := p.id
from Product p
         cross join (
    WITH RECURSIVE getCategories as (
        select id, name, ParentCategoryId as parent_id, updatedAt
        from Category
        where id = @CategoryId
        union
        select category.id, category.name, category.ParentCategoryId as parent_id, parentCategory.updatedAt
        from Category category
                 join getCategories parentCategory on category.id = parentCategory.parent_id
    )
    select *
    from getCategories
) C
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this. I'm using mariadb but I'd prefer to use standard sql since I'm planning on migrating to postgresql.

Comment: If I do that, I'm discarding allí parents in the join since only the corresponding category would match .

Comment: How do i sustitute the parameter leaf_id with the id of the corresponding category?